# URL Routing: a link redirects when not followed by /

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have come across the most bizarre of problems: I have a login page in an MVC application, which when linked by `/login` will automatically redirect to the home page. However, if I use `/Login` or `/login/`, it works!

I have no idea whether it's something to do with a configuration I've messed up, or a configuration in the routing I've played around with, but it happens exclusively with the login page.

I am using forms authentication, and have tried changing the page that you're redirected to from the login page, but that doesn't seem to help at all.

Any ideas?

**Update**: this only happens on my local machine. I host with Windows Azure, and it works fine when deployed.

**Edit**: current routing configuration:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Index", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );

    routes.LowercaseUrls = true;
}
```

Comment: Please include your routing configuration.

Comment: maybe you have routing setup inside IIS? your web.config may have some clues, please include it in question

Comment: @Dima I can assure you that there is no routing in the web.config file